# Use result from if statement in another if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, int, jbutton, actionlistener

I am writing a quiz app, where you get marks as you answer the correct questions and your score increases, and I have to use if statements. Please does any one know how to use a value in an if statement in another if statement! I'm kinda confused about it and its hooking me up at work here....Thanks for the help!... here is a little code example;

```
     int x = 3;
        String xy = Integer.toString(x);
        int y = 0;
        String yy = Integer.toString(y);

        JButton one = new JButton ("Quest 1");
        one.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) {
        JFrame ex = new JFrame ();
        ex.setTitle("Question 1);
        ex.setSize(400, 400);
        ex.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ex.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel ey = new JLabel ("What is the capital of Japan?);
        Font tan = new Font ("Script MT Bold", Font.BOLD, 18);
        ey.setFont(tan);
        ey.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        ex.add(ey, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton answ = new JButton("submit");

        JTextField g = new JTextField (10);
        g.setFont(tan);

        String ans = "Tokyo";

        String merit = "Correct";
        String flop = "wrong";
        String mer = merit + ans;
        String flip = flop + ans;
    answ.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent p) {

        if (g.getText.equals("Tokyo") {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mer);
            one.setText(xy);
        }
        else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,flip);
         one.setText(yy);
        }

        //In my next Action Listener, I would love to 
        //pick the score from the previous listener....and add to the next score....
        //So that we have something like ....
        //x(updated from previous listener) + x
          ex.add(g, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
        });
}
});
```

Comment: Please take a little more time and effort to explain your problem as it is quite confusing given the scant information you've supplied.

Comment: why the downvote again?....what's unclear about the question?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you've not posted a [mcve] for one, and have not yet clarified your if within an if bit.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can guess at in the code supplied is that you're testing if a JTextField's text contains a specific String, "Tokyo" in your GUI creational code. This is code that runs at GUI creation and before the user has had any chance to enter data. To fix this, the if test should be within some listener, perhaps a JButton's ActionListener. Otherwise I have no idea what you mean by if within an if.

---

**Edit**

Regarding your new information:

> I am writing a quiz app, where you get marks as you answer the correct questions and your score increases, and I have to use if statements.

You need to completely re-design your code as you're hard coding your code logic within the GUI, making for a very rigid, *huge*, and difficult to enhance program (as you're finding out) since the code logic must change as the state of the program changes.

Instead you should split out your program logic, the "model" from the GUI, the "view", and try to create them and test them independently, something similar to (or equal to) a "Model-View-Controller" or "MVC" program design. Start with the model, the "guts" of the program and create your non-GUI Question class, one with instance fields, methods, and any other supporting classes. Once this has been tested and debugged, then try to create a GUI or view class that can use this model and display its state. You might also want to create a "Controller" class with listeners that help connect the view to the model.

For example, if your quiz is to be a multiple-choice type of program, then consider:

- A Question class that contains the question String, possible answer Strings and the correct answer String.
- Give it a `public boolean test(String testString)` that returns true if the correct answer String is passed into it.
- Allow the Question class to randomize the order of the possible answer Strings, likely held in an ArrayList.
- Then create a Quiz class that holds an ArrayList of Questions.

Then create a GUI to display these.

- I generally create GUI's that are geared to create JPanels, not JFrames for increased flexibility and then create the JFrame when needed.
- Create a QuestionPanel that displays the question String and the randomized possible answer Strings.
- Display the possible answers as JRadioButtons with a ButtonGroup to limit the selection to one.
- etc....

You'll also want a class to read from a text file data for each question, and load that data into the Quiz class.

You'll also want a mechanism to grade.

Comment: Making sense!!.....I've done that already....I just did not want to display much codes..... but then....I need some more syntax on the score increment stuff!

Comment: @Presh_K7: then clarify your question, take time to craft a clear and specific question, boil the essential code to an [mcve]. To help improve your question above please have a look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's an abbreviated version of his wonderful longer post on [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 2):

Please make all required variables as class level variables instead of declaring it in actionlistner method. Class level variables will be visible in all methods so no need to pass those. Declare score variable as class level.

```
    public class ClassTest {
        int score=0;

        public void acgionlistner1(Event ev)
        {
            if(ans.equals(userinput))
            {
                score++;
            }
        }
        public void acgionlistner2(Event ev)
        {
            if(ans.equals(userinput))
            {
                score++;
            }
        }
.
.
```